# How do I get Visual Studio Developer Powershell working in Visual Studio Code's integrated terminal?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, terminal

I am trying to create a Visual Studio Developer Powershell profile for Visual Studio Code. Here is what I tried:

```json
"Developer Powershell": {
    "path": "pwsh",
    "args": [
        "-noe",
        "-c",
        "\"&{$vsPath = &(Join-Path ${env:ProgramFiles(x86)} '\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Installer\\vswhere.exe') -property installationpath; Import-Module (Join-Path $vsPath 'Common7\\Tools\\Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevShell.dll'); Enter-VsDevShell -VsInstallPath $vsPath -SkipAutomaticLocation}\""
    ],
    "icon": "terminal-powershell"
}
```

I copied and pasted the arguments from my Windows Terminal profile, which works:

```json
{
    "commandline": "pwsh.exe -noe -c \"&{$vsPath = &(Join-Path ${env:ProgramFiles(x86)} '\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Installer\\vswhere.exe') -property installationpath; Import-Module (Join-Path $vsPath 'Common7\\Tools\\Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevShell.dll'); Enter-VsDevShell -VsInstallPath $vsPath -SkipAutomaticLocation}\"",
    "icon": "C:\\powershell\\713\\assets\\Square44x44Logo.png",
    "name": "Developer PowerShell",
    "startingDirectory": "%USERPROFILE%",
}
```

However, terminal output looks like this:

```
&{ = &(Join-Path C:\Program Files (x86) '\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe') -property installationpath; Import-Module (Join-Path  'Common7\Tools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevShell.dll'); Enter-VsDevShell -VsInstallPath  -SkipAutomaticLocation}
  StaggoSTD   
```

*Note: I am using Oh My Posh here. That's why the last line looks weird without a nerd font.*

So how do I make the Developer Powershell work? I tried using `powershell` instead of `pwsh` and removing the escaped double quotes but that did nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr**

The following - which can be used as a property inside the `"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows"` property of your `settings.json` file in order to define a *terminal profile* named `Developer PowerShell` - fixes the problems with your original attempt.

```json
"Developer Powershell": {
  "path": "pwsh",
  "args": [
    "-noexit",
    "-c",
    "$vsPath = & \"${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}/Microsoft Visual Studio/Installer/vswhere.exe\" -property installationpath; Import-Module \"$vsPath/Common7/Tools/Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevShell.dll\"; Enter-VsDevShell -VsInstallPath $vsPath -SkipAutomaticLocation"
  ],
  "icon": "terminal-powershell"
}
```

Note:

- Do *not* use this shell profile as your *default* profile - *unless* you've also configured explicitly configured an *automation* shell to be used for *tasks* and *debugging*, via a `"terminal.integrated.automationProfile.windows"` property - see [Terminal Profiles](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/profiles).

  - The problem is that automation operations pass *additional* command(s) to execute, and Visual Studio Code passes them by *blindly appending* `-Command <command>` to the shell command line (`/d /c <command>` if `cmd.exe` is the shell), which *breaks* if the shell profile itself already defines *commands* (rather than mere *options*) to execute on startup.
- Given that the assumption that environment variable `ProgramFiles(x86)` expands to `C:\Program Files (x86)` is pretty safe (though it *is* possible for it to expand to a different path on unusually configured systems), [your own solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68638892/45375), which avoids use of `${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}`, should typically work just fine.
- The solution above still uses `${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}`, and makes it work by including it in an embedded expandable string (`\"...\"`) that constructs the path strings *directly*, not via `Join-Path`. This not only simplifies the command, it avoids one of the original problems: use of `${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}` *outside of a (PowerShell) string literal*; the next section explains *why* that is a problem.
- Another simplification is the use of `/` as the path separator - which PowerShell accepts interchangeably with `\` - which doesn't require escaping inside a *JSON* string.

---

**Background information:**

- Since **you're passing the PowerShell CLI arguments as an *array*, via the `"args"` property, you should *not* additionally enclose the string passed to the `-c` parameter in an *embedded, escaped* `"..."` string (`\"...\"`)**, because with `"args"` it is *Visual Studio Code* that performs any necessary escaping when stitching together the command line ultimately invoked behind the scenes.

  - If you do use enclosure in `\"...\"`, PowerShell ultimately sees your commands as a single, [expandable string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375), whose expanded value is implicitly echoed - that is the symptom you saw; in simple terms, PowerShell ended up executing something like `"$vsPath = ..."`, which attempts to expand (interpolate) variable `$vsPath`, and since no such variable exists, it evaluates to the *empty string*, causing the following verbatim string to be output:  `= ...`
  - To put it differently: **With `"args"`, you needn't worry about quoting *for the command line*: You simply formulate what each argument should be *verbatim*, and let VS Code do the escaping** - however, **there is *JSON*-related escaping you *do* need to perform**, and there's **the pitfall of VS Code rather than PowerShell potentially *up-front* expanding variable references** such as `${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}`:

    - **JSON-escaping**: Escape embedded **`"` as `\"`, `\` as `\\`**; note that the pain of the latter can be eased by using `/` as the path separator instead, which PowerShell accepts interchangeably with `\`.
    - **VS Code up-front variable expansion pitfall**:

      - VS Code only considers references of the form **`${someName}` and `${someNameSpace:someName}`** candidates for up-front expansion - not also `$someName` and `$someNameSpace:someName`
      - Therefore, typical PowerShell variable references such as `$vsPath` or `$env:USERNAME` are *not* subject to potential up-front expansion, but it *may* happen in cases where enclosure in `{...}` is syntactically *required* in PowerShell, due to a *nonstandard name* such as `${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}`.
      - **With the `env:` namespace, specifically, up-front expansion *always* happens** (as with `command:`, `config:`, and `input:`, but these aren't typically defined in PowerShell): VS Code expands a reference such as `${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}` to the *verbatim value* of that environment variable. That is, `${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}` is replaced with verbatim `C:\Program Files (x86)` in the command string *before*  PowerShell sees the string, and the *lack of quoting* around the value then causes a *syntax error*.
      - While this up-front expansion cannot be *suppressed*, **a simple solution is to enclose the reference *in quotes*: `'${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}'` or `\"${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\"`**. Note that this assumes that the value itself contains no `'`  or `"`, respectively; in cases where this assumption cannot be made, use the following workaround:
        `(Get-Content 'env:ProgramFiles(x86)')`
- As an aside: It is unnecessary to enclose statements passed to `-c` (`-Command`) in `& { ... }` - just use `...` (the statements) directly.

  - Older versions of the [CLI documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) erroneously suggested that `& { ... }` is required, but this has since been corrected.

Comment: For some reason I had to use `"path": "powershell"` instead of `pwsh` (Using Windows 10 21H2)

Comment: @d2weber: `powershell.exe` is the CLI of _Windows PowerShell_, the legacy PowerShell edition that ships with Windows (whose latest and last version is v5.1). `pwsh.exe` is the CLI of [_PowerShell (Core) 7+_](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), the modern, install-on-demand, cross-platform edition.

Comment: thanks for the explaination. I [installed](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell#get-powershell) pwsh. But the problem why I tried to use pwsh instead of powershell didn't resolve: I configured the profile as default. Running a task with `"type": "shell"` results in the following error: `x86: The term 'x86' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.`
Seems like VSCode uses a different kind of escaping in that case. As a workaround I could set `terminal.integrated.automationShell`

Comment: @d2weber - He is basically saying that profile doesn't work because the `\"` sequences aren't working as you are intending in vscode.  The installation path isn't actually being assigned to the variable.

Comment: @elikakohen, the ``\"`` sequences work correctly, but I missed the _task_ angle in d2weber's comment: indeed, you cannot use the shell profile in this answer for _automation_ purposes with `"type": "shell"`, because that will cause the `"command"` value to blindly be appended as `-Command <command>` to the command line that results from the shell profile's own definition, resulting in a broken command.

Answer (score 2):

I have figured it out. Firstly, I would like to give credit to [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0), who has submitted an answer on simplifying the arguments, however it has been deleted. Using this, I replaced `${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}` with `'C:\\Program Files (x86)'` and everything went smoothly. To check if everything was properly working, I ran `gcm fsi`, which told me that F# Interative was there, even though it is not on my normal `PATH`. Here is my profile now for anybody who wants Developer Powershell in VSCode:

```json
"Developer Powershell": {
    "path": "pwsh",
    "args": [
        "-noe",
        "-c",
        "$vsPath = &(Join-Path 'C:\\Program Files (x86)' '\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Installer\\vswhere.exe') -property installationpath; Import-Module (Join-Path $vsPath 'Common7\\Tools\\Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevShell.dll'); Enter-VsDevShell -VsInstallPath $vsPath -SkipAutomaticLocation"
    ],
    "icon": "terminal-powershell"
}
```

As for why the environment variable was there, I copied and pasted from [a Microsoft blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-pnp-blog/add-developer-powershell-and-developer-command-prompt-for-visual/ba-p/2243078). Because it worked for Windows Terminal, I thought it worked for VSCode too. However, every other place I looked for a Developer Powershell profile, the environment variable wasn't used. Later on, I found out that I can just copy from the shortcut at `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Visual Studio 2019\Visual Studio Tools`.

Comment: Nice - using a _quoted (PowerShell) string literal_ in lieu of `${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}` indeed avoids one of the original problems. Please note that I've since undeleted my answer; please see the comments there.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of challenges to customizing PowerShell Integrated Terminal Profiles to work together with `Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevShell.dll`:

- Use the latest version of PowerShell, (not `PowerShell.exe`, but `pwsh.exe`).
- There is a "defect" in Visual Studio Code that injects a `-Command` when using the `"terminal.integrated.automationProfile.windows"` in `settings.json`. So, don't use it. Instead...
- Directly configure Visual Studio Code's Task with `Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevShell.dll`. Kind of a pain, but it will have to do until the `"terminal.integrated.automationProfile.windows"` works as expected.

**Configuring the integrated terminal profile:**

```
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Developer PowerShell",
    "terminal.integrated.shellIntegration.enabled": false,
    "terminal.integrated.shellIntegration.decorationsEnabled": "both",
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {

    "PowerShell": {
        "source": "PowerShell",
        "icon": "terminal-powershell"
    },
    "Command Prompt": {
        "path": [
            "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
            "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
        ],
        "args": [],
        "icon": "terminal-cmd"
    },
    "Git Bash": {
        "source": "Git Bash"
    },
    "Developer PowerShell": {
        "path": "C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\7\\pwsh.exe",
        "icon": "terminal-powershell",
        "args": [
            "-noexit",
            "-Command",
            "Import-Module 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/Common7/Tools/Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevShell.dll'; Enter-VsDevShell -VsInstallPath 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools' -SkipAutomaticLocation;"
        ]
        
    }
```

**Configuring `Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevShell.dll` for Specific Tasks:**

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [

 {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "MyApp.API - Debug",
            "detail": "Clean and Precompile API.",
            "dependsOn": "MyApp.API - Clean",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "presentation": {
                "clear": false,
                "echo": true,
                "panel": "shared"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$msCompile"
            ],
            "options": {
                "shell": {
                    "executable": "C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\7\\pwsh.exe",
                    "args": [
                        "-NoProfile",
                        "-ExecutionPolicy",
                        "Bypass",
                        "-Command",
                        "Import-Module 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/Common7/Tools/Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevShell.dll'; Enter-VsDevShell -VsInstallPath 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools' -SkipAutomaticLocation;"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "command": "cl.exe",
            "args": [
                "/c",
                "/std:c++20",
                "/permissive-",
                "/await",
                "/bigobj",
                "/utf-8",
                "/MTd",
                "/sdl",
                "/Gr",
                "/GL",
                "/Zo",
                "/Z7",
                "/EHsc",
                "/FC",
                "/Fd:",
                "Build/Debug/pch.pdb",
                "/Fo:",
                "Build/Debug/",
                "Include/pch.cpp",
                "/Ycpch.h",
                "/FpBuild/Debug/pch.pch"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update on what mklement0 previously said (March 2023)**

This worked for me. Modify last argument according to where your Powershell Developer is. I used Windows Terminal Settings to look up the proper path and args for my system.

```
        "Developer PowerShell": {
        "path": "powershell",
        "color": "terminal.ansiMagenta",
        "args": [
            "-NoExit",
            "-Command",
            "$vsPath = & \"${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}/Microsoft Visual Studio/Installer/vswhere.exe\" -property installationpath; Import-Module \"${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/Common7/Tools/Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevShell.dll\"; Enter-VsDevShell cc62515d -SkipAutomaticLocation -DevCmdArguments '-arch=x64 -host_arch=x64'"
            ]
    },
```